# Allowing users access to sql server 2014 analysis server cubes

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, analysis

I am using SQL Server 2014 analysis server and have created a number of cubes. These all function as expected however it seems that only windows users who are in an administrator group can get access. All other users are denied access with the very vague error of 'Communication error'.

If I then add that user to our administrators group within the windows domain they instantly get access. I have defined roles for each cube (within analysis services) and then added both individuals (i.e. their windows domain user id)n as well as their windows domain groups to these roles but they still cannot get access - just get the error 'Communication error'. I am using ADOMD on the client side which I know works because users in the administrators group can see the data.

Does any one have any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they don't have permission to the cube(s). From Management Studio, double click the role and under the Cubes section, make sure the Access value is Read.

Grant cube or model permissions (Analysis Services): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174799%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: thanks but that is exactly what I had done and in fact followed that very TechNet article. I did it all again just in case but still no luck. I have tried both our application as well as EXCEL and no matter what settings are in the roles, if the user is NOT a member of the Admin group they simply cannot access the analysis server. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn140245.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn141154.aspx

### tldr;

You need to maintain an admin user at applicationlevel and try to use normal individual rights for accessing the data.

Comment: Try to give a example instead of just pasting links :)